# How can I calculate the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log_{a} n}{\log_{b} n}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

Let $a$ and $b$ be two integers. How can I calculate the following limit?

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log_{a} n}{\log_{b} n}$$

Comment: Hint: the elements of the sequence do not actually depend on $n$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{\log_a(n)}{\log_b(n)}=\log_a(b)$$
(see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base)).

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log_{a} n}{\log_{b} n}$, Now,if we change bases to e  we get following expressions:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln n/\ln a}{\ln n/ \ln b} =\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln b}{\ln a}=\frac{\ln b}{\ln a} $